# Removing commercial components for Oracle Java SE

Tags: java

According to this news - [Oracle finally targets Java non-payers – six years after plucking Sun](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/12/16/oracle_targets_java_users_non_compliance/).
[Some components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/overview/index.html) of Oracle Java SE require extra license for commercial usage.
Here is key features of Oracle Java SE Advanced & Suite Products :

- Java Mission Control (JMC) - It's shiped with JDK
- Java Flight Recorder (JFR) - It's shiped with JRE
- Java Advanced Management Console (AMC) - It's EAR and required extra installation.
- Microsoft Windows Installer (MSI) Enterprise JRE Installer
- Java Usage Tracker (JUT) - According to the [overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/usage-tracker/overview/toc.htm), it's shiped with JRE

I want to remove these commercial components to prevent possible license issue.
This is what I do so far.
For JMC, I remove `$JDK_HOME/lib/missioncontrol/*` and execute `$JDK_HOME/bin/jmc.exe`. A dialog box popuped with this message:

> The Jmc executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.

I also remove `$JDK_HOME/bin/jmc.exe` and `$JDK_HOME/bin/jmc.ini`.

For JFR, I remove `$JRE_HOME/bin/jfr.dll`, `$JRE_HOME/lib/jfr.jar`, `$JRE_HOME/lib/jfr/*` and execute `java -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder pkg.MyTest` for verification. JVM is not started, it prints following message:

> Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   Failed to start tracing backend.

My questions are:

1. How to remove `Java Usage Tracker (JUT)`? I have no idea where the component is.
2. Is there any other file should be removed for JMC and JFR?
3. For Oracle Java SE, is there any other component or file should be removed?

Comment: You should contact Oracle on the best way to do this.

Comment: [Here's a relevant answer from Oracle](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_se_offerings) to that linked article from The Register

Comment: After you make this many changes, would you not be better off with OpenJDK? Or even Azul Zulu. https://www.azul.com/products/zulu/

Comment: Thanks for the information. For long term consideration, replacing Oracle Java SE with OpenJDK will be a good choose. https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild.offer another OpenJDK binaries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to remove these components.  As long as you don't explicitly enable them you're totally fine.

See the [Java Champions clarification](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17OF811wWjjCnmDPJDD6v2c_nMO93e5evjravdCOkXMQ) to that Register article.